# Nodejs redirect from POST method not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a logout button, which sends a POST request. After that it should redirect the user to the main page, but nothing happens. I also tried to set the status code to 302, 303...

Code:

```js
//on click this is executed
function logout() {
  fetch('/logout', { method: 'POST' });
}
```

```js
//this is called on POST request
const logout = (_req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie('token');
  res.locals.payload = undefined;
  res.redirect('/');                    //problem
};
```

```
//logged requests
POST /logout 302 23 - 0.865 ms
GET / 304 - - 6.058 ms
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this specific snippet. Could you show how this is used in the context of your application?

Comment: Note if you are using an AJAX request to reach that endpoint it won't redirect the user's page, it will just redirect the AJAX request to that location and retrieve whatever data is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `/logout` endpoint accepts GET requests, try redirecting the user there instead. For example:

```js
function logout() {
    document.location = '/logout';
}
```

Otherwise, add a redirect in JavaScript once the cookies are cleared:

```js
async function logout() {
  await fetch('/logout', { method: 'POST' });
  document.location = '/';
}
```